# Removing .ds_store from desktop while still having view hidden files on?

Tags: desktop

I have a .DS_Store on my desktop. Ruins the flow. I want to remove it and have it hidden, but I have hidden files enabled on my mac as I need it. This file however, is annoying.

Answer (score 1):

There is a thorough discussion on this [Superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/31580/show-hidden-files-on-os-x-except-ds-store).

Having a transparent icon that is off the desktop (Kevin Suttle), or a read-only desktop (joshfindit) seem to be the best feasible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle the visibility of hidden files using a keyboard shortcut from a Finder plugin called TotalFinder. Probably not worth the effort of installing it though; I don’t.